# Moving a file using lua script in nextcloud 25

Tags: nextcloud

I want to write a lua script that performs file moving in nextcloud 25. Can anyone provide me a script please?

i tried this script that i found somewhere

function file_move(files, dir)
-- Check if the file exists
if not exists(file) then
return nil
end

-- Get the file name and extension
local file_name, file_extension = file.name(file):match("(.+)%.(.+)")

-- Set the destination folder and new name
dir = dir or file.parent(file)
-- new_name = new_name or file_name

-- Construct the destination path
local destination_path = dir .. "/" .. new_name .. "." .. file_extension

-- Move the file
local success, error_msg = file_move(file, destination_path)

if success then
-- Return the updated file node
return dir
else
-- Return nil if an error occurred
return nil
end
end

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/move-a-file-with-file-move-function-lua-script-solved/163950/2)

An example script:

```
input_files = get_input_files()
if (#input_files ~= 1) then
  abort("More than one file was selected.")
end
file = input_files[1]
destination_path = "/destination_folder"
success = file_move(file, destination_path)
if (success) then
  add_message("File moved!")
else
  abort("Failed to move file")
end
```

Comment: This is a generic script that moves a file. It does not fulfill what you asked in your question.